# Validation was not occurring Asp.net MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Validation was not occurring  Asp.net MVC2, I am using ckeditor Control that why mentioned "[ValidateInput(false)]"

Controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[ValidateInput(false)] 
public ActionResult Create(EventInfo EventInfo)
{
    //
}
```

Model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
[StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Maximum 250 Characters")] 
public string TITLE { get; set; }
```

How can i solve this issue.

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: Validation is not occuring. I mentioned the required field also, i'm ckeditor for paragraph text thatswhy i mentioned validateinput =  false otherwise ckeditor  will not work. but validation also not working give me the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably asking for

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return View(EventInfo);
```